# Android fully shaped Button

Tags: android, button, view, shapes

I tried to change the shape of some Android components like Button or View. What I can do is assign a shape to the background with the onDraw-Method. Well, it looks like reshaped, but the touch-events will still work outside my defined shape. Is there any practicable way to exclude touches outside my shape? Certainly, I could check every position of the mouse-event, but for complexer shapes, I don't know how to check if a point is inside the shape.
Thanks for all your replies.

Simon

Answer (score 2):

You can define the shapes in xml [(as you can see here)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).
e.g. :

drawable/sample_shape.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Then you can use the xml description as a drawable for an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

drawable/samplebutton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/sample_shape" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/sample_shape" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sample_shape" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

in your layoutfile:

```
<ImageButton 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/samplebutton">
</ImageButton>
```

Comment: Sure I can do it like that. But the major problem stays the same. If I define a cricular shape, I do not want it to be touchable outside my shape. For your example, it is touchable outside the circle.

Comment: Ah ok, i thought the ImageButton class does it for you, but it doesn't. Sorry for that.